# Tab key is not working using HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have one issue in Tab key enter using HTML.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
   <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">User Name :</span>
   <div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.uname.$touched && billdata.uname.$invalid }">
      <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" class="form-control" placeholder="add user Name" ng-model="login_name" ng-minlength="6" ng-keypress="clearField('uname');" >
   </div>
</div>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.uname.$error" ng-if="billdata.uname.$touched">
   <p ng-message="minlength" style="color:#F00;">This field is too short.The min length of your user name should be 6.</p>
</div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12" ng-hide="showpass">
   <span style="position:absolute; right:5px; margin-top:6px; top:0px;"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success"ng-mousedown="hideShowPassword();" ng-mouseup="hideShowPassword();" ng-mouseleave="hidePassAfterLeave();"  ><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button></span>
   <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Password :</span>
   <div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.pass.$touched && billdata.pass.$invalid }">
      <input type="{{inputType}}" name="pass" id="passno" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="password" ng-minlength="8" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[_!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/" ng-keypress="clearField('passno');" >
   </div>
</div>
```

In the above code suppose user's focus first in the `user name` field.In this condition when user is pressing tab key focus is not moving to password field but 2 times pressing the tab key the focus is happening on password field.Here i need for first time pressing tab key the focus should go to password field.Please help me.

Comment: The code is working fine for me, there maybe an error in your javascript. Can you give us your code?

Answer (score 0):

Set attribute

```
tabindex="-1"
```

to the posts you want to skip

Check this fiddle:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L1d1yv09/)